# JavaScript: Qual é a diferença entre funções assíncronas e funções normais

Tags: javascript

Eu quero saber qual é a diferença entre usar uma `async function` e uma `function` apenas. Claro, com funções assíncronas pode-se usar `await` e elas retornam uma `Promise`.

Mas há algum outro efeito? Existe alguma diferença na maneira como o código é executado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando uma função normal é executada, é executada **sequencialmente**. Isto é, se tiveres duas funções A() e B() e as executares por essa ordem, a função B() só irá ser chamada quando a função A() terminar a sua execução.

Por contraste, se tiveres uma função assíncrona A() (por exemplo, que realize uma operação de I/O ou outra operação bloqueante), esta pode ser chamada e enquanto a operação é realizada podes executar outra função B() (assíncrona ou não) no contexto principal (main thread). Mais tarde, a função A() irá retornar o seu valor quando terminar a operação e houver disponibilidade da main thread para tal.

Atenção que síncrono/assíncrono não tem a ver com multi-threading.

Comment: Eu tinha a impressão que era isso que acontecia, mas não consegui encontrar nada na internet sobre isso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A você escreve de forma "linear" e não com tantos *callbacks*...
Exemplo:

```js
function resolveDepoisDe2Segundos() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolvido');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function teste() {
  console.log('inicio');
  var resultadoAwait = await resolveDepoisDe2Segundos();
  var resultadoPromisse = resolveDepoisDe2Segundos();
  console.log('resultado await', resultadoAwait);
  console.log('resultado promisse then', resultadoPromisse.then(function(resultado){
    console.log('resultado promisse resolved', resultado);
  }));
  console.log('fim');
}

teste();
```